# There is an error that i don't know how to fix in roblox lua

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local place = game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui

function inventrans(amount)
   if place.inven.InvenSee:FindFirstChild("Lava")then
       place.Lava.Amount.value = place.Amount.value+amount
       script.Parent.Amount = script.Parentarent.Amount-amount 
   else
       game.ReplicatedStorage.StorageIco.Lava:clone(1).Parent = 
          game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.inven.InvenSee.Lava
       place.Lava.Amount.value = place.Amount.value+amount
       script.Parent.Amount = script.Parentarent.Amount-amount
   end
end

inventrans(23)
```

I get the error `Lava is not a valid member of Frame`.

I am trying to make an inventory system for my game but there is an error that I do not know how to fix. please help

Comment: Fix the title and description of the question. Reference [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need help.

Comment: i found out how to put the code on sorry i am new

Comment: No problem. You should also add what you have tried, and what the error is. As of now, all I can see is code without any reference to what is actually wrong.

Comment: it said this as the error "Lava is not a valid member of Frame"

Comment: Ok, I have edited your question, with formatting and the error message. :)

Comment: Do you know what caused that?

Comment: No, sorry, I just saw the formatting and fixed it. Hopefully, someone else will come by and look at your code. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your script is a local script and located inside a tool or the player gui.

game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui will be nil if it's not the case.

Comment: thanks there are no errors any more but it still does not work

Comment: could you help me fix it with the team creat

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you located the object **correctly**.

You should use `:WaitForChild`

**Example:** game.Workspace:WaitForChild("Part")

Which will wait for the part to be added in the Workspace. The reason why you should use it is because your code is ran so fast, the object doesn't have enough time to create the part, so it returns an error. But if you use WaitForChild, it'll wait for the object to load in and then it runs the code.